# Calculating Aitchinson's z transform on a data matrix

Tags: r, transformation

I would like to have a function to calculate the Aitchinson's z transform of a data matrix in R, given by the natural logarithm divided by the geometric mean of each column. I tried with

```
library(psych)
log(data)/geometric.mean(data)
```

but this doesn't work, since R doesn't divide each column by the respective element in the vector output of `geometric.mean(data)`. Any thoughts how I should fix this?

cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapply`  for example:

```
aitchinson <- function(data){
    ldata <- log(data)
    mapply(function(x,y)ldata[,x]/y,
                 seq_len(ncol(ldata)),geometric.mean(data))
}
```

For example:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3),ncol=3,nrow=3)
aitchinson(mat)
```